# How can I track many same ImageTargets in Unity / Vuforia

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

when I put ImageTarget Prefab into Hierarchy view, ARCamera only track 1 marker that is child of ImageTarget instead of all markers it see, so can you tell me how to track all the markers, for example in the picture below, I put 2 same markers next to each other, but the only one can be render (instead of two at the the same time). Thanks a lot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxAmQ.png